# SSMS - Read CSV file in to table

Tags: sql-server, regex, csv, ssms

I'm working with a pipe-delimited CSV, in which some of the records have carriage returns in one of the columns, due to how it was extracted.

Example:

```
Jane|Ward|3     |1          |1     |0     |0     |||3210007      
Sam|Anderson|4     |1          |1     |0     |0     |||3210008      
Andy|Smithson    |1     |1          |0     |0     |0     ||

|        
Henry|Johnson     |1     |1          |1     |0     |1     |Elementary School||900196 
Mary|Smith     |2     |1          |1     |0     |0     |||97 Ford 
Chris|Jones     |3     |1          |1     |0     |0     |||900341       
Allen|Bender    |1     |33fg5      |asdd3 |0     |0     ||

|        
Amy|Peterson|3     |1          |1     |0     |0     |||3210007
```

The records all have 10 columns, so each has 9 pipes. In the example, Andy Smithson's and Allen Bender's records have carriage returns in the 9th column. If any records do have carriage returns, they will always be in the 9th column.

I've figured how how to get the records "cleaned up" using regex in Notepad++, but I'm working with a file that has nearly 70k lines, so I'd like to try to automate this as much as possible, obviously.

Is there a way to read such a file in to a table somehow?

I'd be doing this in versions of SSMS 2008 and later.

[Edit]
I did try this in SSMS Import Wizard. It won't work that way, as each line ends with CRLF (as shown in Notepad++), so the Wizard can't differentiate when the lines with a CRLF need to stay in the record or are in fact the end of a record.

Comment: Did you even google this?

Comment: @rory.ap - Yes. If you can point me to a site that can help me, please do so!

Comment: Look into the BULK INSERT command.

Comment: In SSMS there is data import. Right click database, tasks, import data.

Comment: If you can get the file with a different row terminator other than \r\n or \n then that would make this much easier. -- is it just a carriage return or is it a carriage return with a newline as well?

Comment: @SqlZim, Notepad++ shows it as CRLF. I've tried the SSMS importer (updated my question with that info) Problem is, every line is terminated with CRLF - including the lines in that one column that I'm trying to get on one line

Comment: @marky Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a format file so it will not break early on the `RowTerminator` and continue on until the `FieldTerminator`.

An example xml format file for your data would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RECORD>
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR= '|' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n'  COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  </RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Firstname" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Lastname" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Column3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Column4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Column5" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="Column6" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Column7" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Column8" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Column9" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="Column10" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

and use it like this:

using `bcp`

```
bcp testdb.dbo.target_table IN D:\BCP\bulk_import_file.txt -f D:\BCP\format_file.xml -T
```

---

Note: the file path needs to be accessible from the sql server for the following two options.

using `bulk insert`

```
bulk insert dbo.target_table
  from '...\bulk_import_file.txt'
  with (
    formatfile = '...\format_file.xml'
  , firstrow   = 1 -- set to 2 if it has headers
  --, lastrow    =  /* if you need to skip extra lines at the end */
  , maxerrors  = 0
  , tablock
  );
```

using `openrowset`:

```
select *
from openrowset (
  bulk '...\bulk_import_file.txt'
  , formatfile = '...\format_file.xml'
  , firstrow   = 1 -- set to 2 if it has headers
  --, lastrow    =  /* if you need to skip extra lines at the end */
  , maxerrors  = 0
  ) as o;
```

- [Using the Bulk-Load Tools in SQL Server - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html)
- [XML Format Files (SQL Server) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx)
- [Non-XML Format Files (SQL Server) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx)
- [Import and Export Bulk Data by Using the bcp Utility (SQL Server) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [bcp Utility - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.110).aspx)